# Alert on document library comes through 3 times

Tags: 2010, alert

I am using SharePoint 2010......when I create an Alert I do get an email saying I created the Alert, but when I do something that will kick of the Alert I do get the email that say I added a new document to the library but the email comes through 3 times with the SAME Alert message.

Why is that, anyone know how I can only make sure I get the alert once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please verify how many times you have set an alert on a library?
It is possible you have created the same alert 3 times on a library causing you to receive the alert 3 times.

In the top right click on you username > My Settings > My Alerts

Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Yes, ai thanks, was from my testing of the SMTP server!